# Why if H⊴G and H is solvable and G/H is solvable, then G is also solvable?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Plus, to the proof any p-group G is solvable,although Z(G) is normal to G and which is abelian, but G/Z(G) is not abelian, so what is the chain subgroup to  show that G is solvable?

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$H\;\;\text{solvable}\;\implies\;\exists\;\;\text{an abelian series}\;\;1:=H_0\lhd  H_1\lhd\ldots\lhd H_k:=H$$

$$G/H\;\;\text{solvable}\;\implies\;\exists\;\;\text{an abelian series}\;\;\overline 1:=\overline G_0\lhd \overline G_1\lhd\ldots\lhd\overline G_m:=G/H$$

Use that  $\;G_i=N_i/H\;$ ,  with $\;H\le N_i\le G\;$ , and $\;\overline G_i\lhd\overline G_{i+1}\iff N_i\lhd N_{i+1}$

Now check what happens with the series

$$1=H_0\lhd\ldots\lhd H\lhd N_1\lhd\ldots ...\lhd G$$

Comment: (N.B.: OP will have to use $\bar G/\bar H\simeq G/H$)

Comment: Why they are abelian series? By the definition, only the quotients are abelian.

Comment: @Joseph, that's exactly what abelian series means: the factors are abelian.

Comment: But H is solvable, doesn't mean it's abelian.

Comment: I know that, @Joseph...so what?

Comment: So do you mean H is also abelian? Or why you say by factor is abelian than the chain is abelian?

Comment: No @Joseph, I don't say $\;H\;$ is abelian. And again: a (subnormal) series, or chain if you prefer, is abelian if each factor in it is abelian, meaning : $\;H_i/H_{i-1}\;,\;\;\overline G_i/\overline G_{i-1}\;$ are abelian.

Comment: But how to prove the existence of these Ni?

Comment: The correspondence theorem, @Joseph... this must be old stuff in group theory for you if you already are studying solvable groups.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am taking the modern algebra course, but I haven't seen the corresponding theorem, sorry about that. But right now I got it on line.

Comment: That's odd, @Joseph, as the Correspondence Theorem is one of the most important, basic theorems in elementary group theory and, as far as I can see it, it preceedes solvable groups big time.

Comment: So did you learn the solvable group from modern algebra or other algebra courses?

Comment: In a basic group theory course, which also included a little basic ring theory, @Joseph .