# Let $G$ be a group s.t. $|G|=pqr$ where $p,q,r$ are primes that need not be distinct. Prove that $G$ is soluble.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group s.t. $|G|=pqr$ where $p,q,r$ are primes that need not be distinct. Prove that $G$ is soluble.

So, I don't know whether I should handle this case by case and try to get the Sylow theorems involved or if there is an easier way to do this, a slick trick I am not seeing perhaps. Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: Do you know that groups of order $pqr$ are not simple?

Comment: no i did not know that

Comment: Anyway, you can read my answer here, as well as the comments under the answer. It should answer your question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075129/let-p-q-be-odd-primes-prove-that-a-group-of-order-2-pq-is-solvable/3075152#3075152