# for $H \triangleleft G$, show that $H$ and $G/H$ solvable implies $G$ solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

I have recently begun working my way through Serge Lang's *Algebra*, and on page 19 there is stated that for a group $G$ with a normal subgroup $H$, $G$ is solvable if and only if $H$ and $G/H$ are solvable. However, only the proof of $G$ solvable $\implies H$ solvable is given, with the rest of the statements to be proven as an exercise.

This is my attempt at proving $G$ solvable $\implies G/H$ solvable:

We have $G$ solvable, so that we can find a tower of subgroups
$$
G = G_0 \supset G_1 \supset\cdots\supset G_m = 1
$$
so that the conditions on solvability are met. We then take the quotient so that
$$
G/H = (G/H)\_0\supset (G/H)\_1 \supset\cdots\supset (G/H)\_m = H
$$
where $(G/H)\_j = G_j/H$.

It is then immediately verified that all factor groups in this tower are abelian, as $(G_i/H)/(G_{i+1}/H) = G_i/G_{i+1}$, which is abelian by assumption.

To prove that each $G_{i+1}/H$ is normal in $G_i/H$, take $xH\in G_i/H$, $x^\prime H\in G_{i+1}/H$ and write
$$
(xH)(x^\prime H)(xH)^{-1} = xHx^\prime Hx^{-1}H = xx^\prime x^{-1}H = x^\prime H
$$
As a last step, we refine with the trivial group at the end to obtain the desired tower so that $G$ solvable does indeed imply $G/H$ solvable. The converse seems obvious as well to me.

What I am struggling with, however, is the proof that $H$ solvable $\implies G$ solvable. Here is how far I got:

We write the abelian tower of $H$, and then refine with $G$ on the left since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ so that we have
$$
G = G_0 \supset H = H_0 \supset H_1 \supset\cdots\supset H_m = 1
$$
By assumption, $H$ is normal in $G$ and each $H_{i+1}$ is normal in $H_i$. Likewise, each $H_i/H_{i+1}$ is abelian by assumption, so it only remains to prove that $G/H$ is abelian. This does however not seem like a viable angle of attack on this problem.

> Is the rest of my reasoning valid? How else would one show $H$ solvable $\implies G$ solvable?

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39814/for-g-a-group-and-h-unlhd-g-then-g-is-solvable-iff-h-and-g-h-are-solv?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have read this post, but it is mainly concerned with G solvable implying G/H solvable, something i did not struggle with (and where i already found the holes in my reasoning). My problem is showing that H solvable implies G solvable, which is not really touched on in that post

Comment: What about, for example, [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933146/why-if-h%E2%8A%B4g-and-h-is-solvable-and-g-h-is-solvable-then-g-is-also-solvable)? You can find several proofs about this direction at this site. From $H$ solvable alone, you cannot conclude that $G$ is solvable. Take the trivial group $H=1$ in a simple group $G$.